# NoSuchBeanDefinition: ConfigurableEnvironment

Tags: jhipster

Whenerver I run any microservice I get this exception sooner or later which pops up in my logs every 2 seconds:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {}

unfortunately I have no idea where to define this bean. Any help is appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Have you started the JHipster registry?

Comment: Yes, have everything up an running (registry, 2 services and a gateway)

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3140